# Evaluating line integrals in the form $\oint F\cdot n ds$

Tags: vector-analysis, line-integrals

Let $C$ be the unit circle on the plane, oriented counterclockwise, consider vector field $$F=(x^2,xy)$$
We are asked to find the flux through $C$ by evaluating the line integral $\oint_C F\cdot n ds$, but I am only familiar with line integrals of the form $\oint_C F\cdot  dr$ which is against the tangent as opposed to the normal vector. How do we evaluate this other form?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your backgrounds, so I don't know if I should give you the full explanation, in term of differential forms...

The short answer, indeed, is what follows. Since you want to compute "how much flow" of $F$ is going trough your curve $C$ you have to integrate the inner product of the vectors $F$ with the unit normal vectors of the curve $C$. That is, you compute $C'(t)$ and take $n(t)$ a unit normal vector. The reason is that $F(C(t))\cdot n(t)$ gives you a measurement of how transversal is $F(C(t))$ to $C'(t)$. For example, if $F$ is tangent to $C$ at $C(t)$ then $F(C(t))\cdot n(t)=0$ (no flow of $F$ is going through $C$ locally at $C(t)$).

In particular, you take $C(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t))$, and so $C'(t)=(-\sin(t),\cos(t))$ and
$$
n(t)=(\cos(t),\sin(t)).
$$

So finally
$$
\int_C F\cdot n dt=\int_0^{2\pi} \cos^3(t)+\cos(t)\sin^2(t)dt=\int_0^{2\pi} +\cos(t)dt=...
$$

Comment: So in order to calculate work done we go tangential to the surface and to calculate flux we go normal? Can Greens theorem be applied here and does it determine work done or flux? Also could we not say that k is perpendicular to our surface as it is on the plane?

Comment: Also if there is this idea for work done and flux for line integrals, is there an equivalent idea for work done of surface integrals? I know that you can perform a surface integral to determine flux but how about work done?

Comment: " in order to calculate work done we go tangential to the surface and to calculate flux we go normal?", yes, for the bidimensional case.
Respect to Green theorem, it can be applied in both cases. You have to differentiate a different 1-form in every case (work or flux)

Comment: With respect to work done on surface... I don't think so. Think that what you can do, in the end, is integrate $k$-forms in $k$-submanifolds. So you should find a 2-form representing the force in the surface. Of course you could restrict to curves inside the surfaces...

Comment: Could we instead calculate a surface flux integral and let $F=(x^2,xy,0)$? Would this be equivalent?

Comment: I don't get it. I dont understand what you mean

Comment: As in we can calculate the flux through a 3d surface using surface integrals so what if we just think of our surface as a 3d surface on the xy plane and perform a surface integral on it

Answer (score 0):

The curve $C$ can be given by the parametric equation $r(t):=(\cos t,\sin t) $ over the interval $[0,2\pi[$, since $C$ is a circle of radius $1$.

We can show that the *flux* of the vector field $\vec{F}=(f,g)$ across $C$ is given by $$\int_{C}\vec{F}\cdot \vec{n}\, ds=\int_{C}f\, dy-g\, dx.$$

Thus, since $f=x^2$ and $g=xy$, then
\begin{align*}\int_{C}\vec{F}\cdot \vec{n}\, ds&=\int_{C}x^2\, dy-xy\, dx\\&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}(\cos t)^2\cdot(\cos t)-(\cos t\sin t)(-\sin t)\, dt\\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\cos^{3}t+\cos t\sin^{2} t\, dt\\
&=0.
\end{align*}

Also,  we can use Green's theorem in Normal form:

$$\int_{C}\vec{F}\cdot \vec{n}\, ds=\iint_{R}{\rm div}(\vec{F})\, dA=\iint_{R}3x\, dA=0,$$
where $R$ is the region closed by the circle $x^2+y^2=1$.

N.B: It is also interesting notice since  $0=f_y\not=g_x=y$, then $\vec{F}$ is not conservative.

Comment: In your first formula, shouldn't be $fdy-gdx$?

Comment: Yes, you are right.I made a mistake in the calculation. I will correct it shortly. Thanks. @A.J.Pan-Collantes